# How do you differentiate a function with respect to the negative of its variable?

Tags: derivatives

How do you differentiate a function with respect to the negative of its variable. For example, is it true that df(-x)/dx = - df(x)/dx? If so, why is it?

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Answer (score 3):

It is confusing because you are using $x$ in two ways: as the argument of $f$ and as the variable you vary.  $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ refer to two different arguments of $f$, and the values  may have nothing to do with each other.  For example, take $f(x)=x$.  Then $f(-x)=-x$ and $\frac {df(-x)}{dx}=-1=-\frac {df(x)}{dx}$  On the other hand,take $f(x)=x^2$, so $f(-x)=f(x)$ Then the derivatives are equal, not negatives.  What is true is $\frac {df(x)}{d(-x)}=-\frac {df(x)}{dx}$, but this is not the same thing.

Comment: Can you give a proof that  df(x)d(−x)=−df(x)dx ?

Comment: That follows from the chain rule.  Define $u=-x$ and you want $\frac {df(x)}{du}$